# android listview repeating some items on listitem click event

Tags: android, listview

This is my screen shot of application,

[image]

This is 1 list item (contains 1 imageview and 3 imagebutton and id).I have 50 ListItem in my ListView Like this.

in this  when user clicks on like button(first button) the value update and set text to that specific position(this is working) But it repeat the value like this(when clicking on first like button-> Position 0 then it repeats value for 4th,7th,etc...Position.

How to Resolve problem for Repeating set Text for Every 4th Item?

Please guide me.
Thanks in Advance.

My Code is,
/** Adapter Class */

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
        ImageView imgUnlike[] = null, imgLike[] = null,
                imgComments[] = null;
        TextView txtLikeUnlike[] = null, txtComments[] = null,

        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr = null;
        Context context = null;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
        HashMap<String, String> getData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String urlLike = null, urlCountLike = null, urlUnlike = null;
        String strCountLike = null, strCountCommnets = null;

        public Adapter1(Context context,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr) {

            this.context = context;
            this.arr = arr;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.imgUnlike = new ImageView[arr.size()];
            this.imgLike = new ImageView[arr.size()];
            this.imgComments = new ImageView[arr.size()];
            this.txtLikeUnlike = new TextView[arr.size()];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arr.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return arr.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                        .getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
                        false);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
            }
            /** Initialize Widgets */
            /** Imageview */

            imgUnlike[position] = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgUnlike);

            imgLike[position] = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgLike);


            /** TextView */
            txtLikeUnlike[position] = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtLikeUnlike);

            getData = arr.get(position);





            txtLikeUnlike[position].setText(getData
                    .get(Fragment1.TAG_TOTAL_LIKE_COUNT));



            imgUnlike[position]
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            imgUnlike[position]
                                    .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            imgLike[position]
                                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            strPostId = arr.get(position).get(
                                    Fragment1.TAG_POST_ID);

                            urlLike = Urls.BASE_URL
                                    + "createpostlike.php?post_id=" + strPostId
                                    + "&user_id=" + myDetail.getUserId();

                            getCurrentPosition = position;
                            new sendLikeData().execute();
                        }
                    });

            imgLike[position].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imgLike[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    imgUnlike[position].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    urlGetAllLike = Urls.BASE_URL + "getlike.php";

                    getCurrentPosition = position;
                    new getAllLikeData().execute();
                }
            });


            return row;
        }




public class sendLikeData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
                String jsonStr = sh
                        .makeServiceCall(urlLike, ServiceHandler.GET);

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                urlCountLike = Urls.BASE_URL + "getalllike.php?post_id="
                        + strPostId;
                new getCountLikeData().execute();
            };
        }


/** Count the Total Like for Selected Items. */
        private class getCountLikeData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            JSONObject jsonobject;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlCountLike);
                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = jsonarray.length() - 1; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        strCountLike = jsonobject.getString("Total");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                txtLikeUnlike[getCurrentPosition].setText(strCountLike);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67120/discussion-between-suhail-mehta-and-reena).

Answer (score -1):

I think your adapter class will be something similar like below using viewholder:

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {


    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr = null;
    Context context = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    HashMap<String, String> getData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String urlLike = null, urlCountLike = null, urlUnlike = null;
    String strCountLike = null, strCountCommnets = null;

    public Adapter1(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr) {

        this.context = context;
        this.arr = arr;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.imgUnlike = new ImageView[arr.size()];
        this.imgLike = new ImageView[arr.size()];
        this.imgComments = new ImageView[arr.size()];
        this.txtLikeUnlike = new TextView[arr.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arr.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        View row = null;
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
                    false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imgUnlike[position] = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgUnlike);

            holder.imgLike[position] = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgLike);


            /** TextView */
            holder.txtLikeUnlike[position] = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtLikeUnlike);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        /** Initialize Widgets */
        /** Imageview */


        getData = arr.get(position);




        holder.txtLikeUnlike[position].setText(getData
                .get(Fragment1.TAG_TOTAL_LIKE_COUNT));



        holder.imgUnlike[position]
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        holder.imgUnlike[position]
                                .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.imgLike[position]
                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        holder.strPostId = arr.get(position).get(
                                Fragment1.TAG_POST_ID);

                        urlLike = Urls.BASE_URL
                                + "createpostlike.php?post_id=" + strPostId
                                + "&user_id=" + myDetail.getUserId();

                        getCurrentPosition = position;
                        new sendLikeData().execute();
                    }
                });

        holder.imgLike[position].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.imgLike[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.imgUnlike[position].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                urlGetAllLike = Urls.BASE_URL + "getlike.php";

                getCurrentPosition = position;
                new getAllLikeData().execute();
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgUnlike[] = null, imgLike[] = null,
                imgComments[] = null;
        TextView txtLikeUnlike[] = null, txtComments[] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Reena, create constructor of your asynctask and pass holder in it when you are calling asynctask.

Comment: tell me the reason whoever give downvote this answer.

Comment: holder.imgUnlike[position] = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgUnlike); you have this in null convertView  check so, you have only position 0 set in tag of holder. Then you are accessing it with any other position apart from 0 here  holder.txtLikeUnlike[position] = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtLikeUnlike); this will give you result at so other refrence. Think you understood

Comment: @SuhailMehta Please send me sample code of View Holder with using array of ImageView.

Comment: @SuhailMehta I am using ViewHolder then again face Same Problem

Comment: @SuhailMehta i think you didnt read my first line of answer. i posted this answer for her reference only for how to use viewholder. and not giving exact code..

Comment: @SuhailMehta i think you also not understand the concept of viewholder.. its better to ask Reena that she is getting any error for that or not OR you can run my code,so you can get idea..

Comment: whats the use of keeping imageView reference in array when you are explaining view re-usability here by showing view holder pattern concept?

Comment: @SuhailMehta i didnt know the purpose of her for that. i already told that i was just give her example for how to use viewholder. kindly please check my first line of answer. its realy good if you are give chance to her for judging my answer rather than yourself again and again.

Answer (score -1):

This is the pseudo code add the desired code at specific comments

```
public class LikeModel{

private String likes ;

public void setLikes(String likes){
this.likes = likes ;
}

public String getLikes(){
return likes ;
}

}
```

Now when you are getting data from server just set the likes value there and pass the model to the adapter or you can use Gson where you can integrate this bean with your server data

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {


        public Adapter1(Context context,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr) {

           // your own implementation or reference check here
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arr.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return arr.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
               ayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
                    false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.YOUR_LIKE_TEXT_VIEW = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_id);
            // Same way refer other view(like image view etc)

           convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            LikeModel model = likeModelArray.get(position);

            holder.YOUR_LIKE_TEXT_VIEW.setText(model.getLikes());

            holder.YOUR_LIKE_IMAGE.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    urlGetAllLike = Urls.BASE_URL + "getlike.php";

                    getCurrentPosition = position;
                    new getAllLikeData().execute(PASS POISTION HERE);
                }
            });


            return row;
        }
```

Then Async Task

```
public class sendLikeData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
                String jsonStr = sh
                        .makeServiceCall(urlLike, ServiceHandler.GET);

                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                urlCountLike = Urls.BASE_URL + "getalllike.php?post_id="
                        + strPostId;
                new getCountLikeData().execute();
            };
        }


/** Count the Total Like for Selected Items. */
        private class getCountLikeData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);



                LikeModel model = likeModelArray.get(position);
                model.setLikes(SET COUNTER VALUE HERE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                // 

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for Give me demo

Comment: Further discussion tomorrow